# not playing media files like mp3 mp4 and permission denied on apache server

Tags: apache2, lighttpd

On apache server I configured tomcat as proxy server that serves mp3 and mp4 from a folder named content. I have given 0755 permission recursively to all media files and changed owner group to root recursively. Media content is played on Firefox but not chrome and edge browser.
I have added media type to httpd.conf file also.

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
```

Still not working. It says forbidden. You don't have permission to access folder on this server.403 error

Comment: "and changed owner group to root recursively" this is bad. It needs to be the apache user and group. Please add the install method used for all 3 browsers: are chrome and edge SNAP installs? If so snaps are confined (sandboxed) to their own read only filesystem.  You should use non-snap versions.

Comment: Yeah i understood but it does not solve my problem.

Comment: all browsers are installed on window 10 and i am accessing content through apache web server. I can access image files from the same folder where mp3 mp4 content are placed but i cannot access mp3,mp4 files

Comment: Is the Apache directory on the server local or a network mount? If you are hosting files that are stored on a Samba share, then you will likely need to modify the Apache config just a bit to include some extra meta 

Comment: its on server local

Comment: mp3 mp4 links works on firefox but not on chrome and edge